# subclass val for using in base constructor

Tags: kotlin

I am producing a kotlin library which is an equivalent to an existing python library.  Producing an equivalent to code in another language can be a challenge.

Specifically I have the case of a base class constructor method which makes use of a value which can be overridden in the base class.

The challenge is that a val overridden in sub-class has not had the value applied prior to the base class constructor.  In python, some code in a sub class constructor can execute prior to calling the base class constructor, but in kotlin all code of the base class constructor executes first.

But consider this kotlin code:

```
open class Base{
    val simple = 3
    open val open = 3
    open val openGet = 3
    open val getter get()= 3
    open val getOpen get()= 3
    open val getDelg by GetDelg(3)
    init {
        println("base simple $simple open $open openG $openGet "+
                "getOpen $getOpen getter $getter "+
                " getDelg $getDelg")
    }
    //open fun add(a:Int,b:Int) = a + b
}

class SubClass:Base(){
    override val open = 4
    override val openGet get()= 4
    override val getter get() = 4
    override val getOpen = 4
    //override val getDelg by GetDelg(4)  //uncomment for null pointer
    init {
        println("sub simple $simple open $open openG $openGet "+
                "getOpen $getOpen getter $getter "+
                " getDelg $getDelg")

    }
}
class GetDelg(val value:Int){
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): Int {
        return value
    }
}
```

Open is 0 in the base class init because the code to set the value has not yet been run (not 3 as that is in super.open which is separate).

openG, a value overridden by a get() method, perhaps unexpectedly returns the override value in both init() methods, so this is a possible approach for many cases, but not working in the specific case I am trying to solve.

getOpen, a get() method in the base overridden by a simple initialisation, behaves as a simple initialised value overridden by a new initialise, which is to be unitialised in the base init() method

getter() , a get() method overidden by another get() method returns the override value as does openG

getDelg() actually generates a null pointer exception if called during  the base init() method, as the overridden value has not been calculated

Note: I assume part of this behaviour is base on the fact that overridden properties are actually new distinct properties, so they do not inherit values from base class property which is still accessible via super..  This means, counter intuitively, that open in the base `init()` method, returns 0, while super.open in the subclass `init()` will return 3

So the problem is, how can i override using a delegate, but still have the override delegate accessed in the base class init?

My current thought is to move the value initialised in the base class to a lazy property, but I would like to have other ideas.

Comment: Accessing non-final properties or calling non-final methods in constructors is generally a bad idea, both in Kotlin and Java. If you need certain values in your base class, you should try passing them up via constructor parameters.

Comment: clearly on the 'is a bad idea'...in fact you could say...'will not work' :) .   But i am looking at two aspects, one is the sub class is the use of the package, the package is the base class.   So the goal is to have all functionality possible in the base class and minimise code required in the sub class.  But you have given me the idea to test if accessing the delegated val as a parameter will force it to be initialised.  Messy but perhaps better than nothing